# $f$ is analytic with range as a circle

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity, constants

I was given that range of $f$ lies on a cirlce, and $f$ is analytic on $D$. I want to show that $f$ is constant.

This is my approach: I suppose that $f$ lies on a circle $|w-P|=R$, where $P,R$ are constants. Then consider $|f(z)-P|=R \longrightarrow |f(z)-P|^2=f(z)^2+P^2=R^2$, which means $f(z)=\sqrt{R^2-P^2}$, so $f(z)$ is a constant.

In the above approach, I did not use the fact that $f$ is analytic on $D$.  Is it okay to use the argument that I used.

Comment: How do you get $|f(z)-P|^2=f(z)^2+P^2$?

Comment: It is easiest to develop the open mapping theorem, and conclude that $f$ must be constant because the circle does not contain an open set.

Comment: @ajd: can i change that to real part of f and P squared, and then imaginary part of f squared?